# PHP iframe redirect to another page?

Tags: php, html, iframe

As of right now I'm trying to do an echo with php without it being on it's own name.php page, but instead on my index.html, right under the submit button.

Current html code:

```
 <form autocomplete="off" action="test.php" method="post" target="iframe" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <p>Passcode:</p>
  <input type="password" name="code"/><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
  <iframe name="iframe"></iframe>
</form>
```

Current php code:

```
$testcode = ("123");

  } else if ($pass === $testcode) {
    header('location: test.html');
  } else {
    echo "Try Again!";
  }
```

It kind of works, except if it's successful the page doesn't redirect to test.html but tries to goto test.html within the iframe.
However, if I set the form target to _self it redirects to test.html, but doesn't echo "Try again" in the iframe.

So how would I go about redirecting to test.html if correct code is put in, and print "Try Again" underneath the submit button if code is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve this using php. Because

> PHP is a server side language.

**Opening new window is a client side action**

So you need to use Jquery or javascript for this.